# UITableView cells with buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to have a UIButton in each UITableViewCell that will allow me to perform selector on the object corresponding to that row.  They way I got it working was to create a separate UITableViewCell for each row (no reuse), add a new UIButton that is tagged with the row.  When the button gets tapped, the resulting selector checks the tag of the sender to determine which object to change.

Is there a better way of doing this?  For one, I am not reusing cells which is unfortunate, and using UIView.tag seems very hacky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same tag number on all of the UIButtons.

To extract the row number which has been clicked, implement this code in the selector:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender

{

    UITableViewCell * clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];

    NSIndexPath * clickedButtonPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

    int rownumber = clickedButtonPath.row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a subclass of UITableViewCell so that it stores a reference to a button. Then set that button when you dequeue a cell. In the method that is called, sender will be the button and you can ask for it's superview and then ask that (which is the cell) for it's index.